# Rewriting to remove part of URL when additional URL parts exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a number of legacy URLs with the directory structure as:

http://domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/

I would like to remove "dir1" from the URL, in all cases except for when "dir1" is requested by itself, e.g. as http://domain.com/dir1/

Is this possible with mod_rewrite or am I overcomplicating things?  Would I be better to rename "dir1" and create an additional rule to redirect requests to that specific director?

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this rewrites all instances of dir1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your capture group to use `.+` instead. that way there *has* to be something after the `dir1`:

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Good to know I was on the right track with my attempt!